# Unable to use the Calibri font in advanced pdf template

Tags: fonts, netsuite

I am unable to use the Calibri font in the netsuite advanced pdf/html template

```
<style>
p{
font-famly: Calibri,sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calibri is not one of the standard fonts available to all PDF documents.  This means in order to use it, you need to embed it in your PDF, by using the `<link>` element in your template.  How to do this is demonstrated below:

```
<pdf> 
  <head> 
    <link name="mytimes" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="calibri.ttf" bytes="1"/> 
  </head> 
    <body font-family="calibri" font-size="18"> 
      Hello in an embedded ClearType font 
    </body> 
</pdf>
```

Of course, your source attribute needs to point to a file containing the font(s) you want to embed in a location the template can access.

Further information on this can be found in the [BFO Report Generator User Guide](https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/userguide.pdf) under Fonts - starting on about page 30.

Comment: need more information. The font still not being set. Also the font is not available in WYSIWYG mode.